# How to calculate time difference between two succesive rows with groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation, timedelta

I have the following dataset of students taking multiple SAT exams:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'student': 'A A A A A B B B C'.split(),
                  'exam_date':[datetime.datetime(2013,4,1),datetime.datetime(2013,6,1),
                               datetime.datetime(2013,7,1),datetime.datetime(2013,10,2),
                               datetime.datetime(2014,1,1),datetime.datetime(2013,11,2),
                               datetime.datetime(2014,2,2),datetime.datetime(2014,5,2),
                               datetime.datetime(2014,5,2)]})

print(df)

  student  exam_date
0       A 2013-04-01
1       A 2013-06-01
2       A 2013-07-01
3       A 2013-10-02
4       A 2014-01-01
5       B 2013-11-02
6       B 2014-02-02
7       B 2014-05-02
8       C 2014-05-02
```

I want to create a new column `diff` with the difference of two successive exam dates for each individual student, and then filter the value with a particular threshold, i.e. `75 days`. If the student doesn't have two successive dates, we need to drop that student.

I am trying the following script to create the new column:

```
df['exam_date'] = df.groupby('student')['exam_date'].apply(lambda x: x.sort_values())

df['diff'] = df.groupby('student')['exam_date'].diff() / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')

print(df)

  student  exam_date  diff
0       A 2013-04-01   NaN
1       A 2013-06-01  61.0
2       A 2013-07-01  30.0
3       A 2013-10-02  93.0
4       A 2014-01-01  91.0
5       B 2013-11-02   NaN
6       B 2014-02-02  92.0
7       B 2014-05-02  89.0
8       C 2014-05-02   NaN
```

Then I'm using `query` to filter the value and get the output:

```
df_new = df.query('diff <= 75')

print(df_new)

  student  exam_date  diff
1       A 2013-06-01  61.0
2       A 2013-07-01  30.0
```

This is correctly selecting the student `A` and removing the students `B` and `C`. However, I'm missing the earliest date for the student `A`.

Though using `df[df['student'].isin(studentList)]`I'm getting the desired result, but it's too much of work.

Is there any better way of getting the desired output, maybe using `diff()` and `le()`? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your shown output doesn't seem to match the threshold. Why do we keep B if there are no dates that are less than the threshold of 75 days or does the filled 0 count? What is expected output for the provided input?

Comment: @HenryEcker As far as I understand the post, students are kept iff their exam-date-differences are below the threshold.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is filtering students, but you are filtering exam records.

After you got `df_new`, just find the students set, and use that to select `df`:

```
df[df.student.isin(df_new.student.unique())]
```

and you'll get:

```
 student  exam_date  diff
0       A 2013-04-01   NaN
1       A 2013-06-01  61.0
2       A 2013-07-01  30.0
3       A 2013-10-02  93.0
4       A 2014-01-01  91.0
```

Comment: `studentList` is actually `df_new.student.unique()`. Thanks for your respond @songziming